# marathon version 1.1.1--can't get task state?

Tags: mesos, marathon

I noticed that in version 1.4.3 the app/tasks task JSON contains the state field. However, in version 1.1.1 I don't see it.

Is there some config param I need to set so that the state field is retrieved for each task?

Thanks

--John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest (and final) 1.1.x release is 1.1.7, and, unfortunately, does not include a parameter to expose this information. You will need to upgrade to a later release of Marathon (1.3.x) to access it.

Perhaps this is helpful: you can specify the query string parameter "?status=running" to cause only running tasks to be returned.